# Splitting a string into tokens and putting tokens into array - strtok

Tags: c, arrays, output, strtok

```
char** token_arr(char* str, int n_tokens)
{
   char**arr = malloc((n_tokens+1)*sizeof(char*));
   char str2[n_tokens + 1];
   strcpy(str2,str);
   int i = 0;
   char *p = strtok (str2, " ");

   while (p != NULL)
   {
       arr[i] = p;
       //printf("%s\n", arr[i]);
       p = strtok (NULL, " ");
       i++;
   }
 return arr;
}
```

The purpose of token_arr is to get a string and a number of tokens, then put the tokens into an array. The array of tokens is returned.

```
int main(void) {
  char*str1 = "( 8 + ( 41 - 12 ) )";
  char**expression = token_arr(str1, 9);
  for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    printf("expression[%d] = %c\n", i, *expression2[i]);
 return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
expression2[0] = (
expression2[1] = 
expression2[2] = 
expression2[3] = 
expression2[4] = 
expression2[5] = 
expression2[6] = 
expression2[7] = 
expression2[8] =
```

Why is only the first value being printed? What's wrong with my code?

Comment: You are allocating the array of pointers, but the pointers point to a local variable, `str2`, in the function, and that variable is out of scope once you're back in `main()`, so you're accessing invalid data that has been reused and presumably zeroed.  You'll need to allocate the string where you copy the string literal, and you'll need to find a way to pass both allocated pointers back to the `main()` so you can free the allocated memory accurately.  As it stands, you have 'undefined behaviour'.  That means that what you see is a valid response, as are many other possible behaviours.

Comment: Unless you are using `calloc` or `memset` to preserve a *sentinel NULL* at the end of `arr`, there is no need for `+1` in `char**arr = malloc((n_tokens+1)*sizeof(char*));`. `arr` is simply the number of pointers you are allocating. If you only have `n_tokens` you only need that number of pointers unless you are ensuring you have the final pointer `NULL` to allow iteration with a `while` loop -- but in that case you need to set ALL pointers `NULL` to begin with.

Comment: You also need to avoid writing to more pointers than you have. So you need to ensure `i` never exceeds `n_tokens+1` as you currently have it, e.g. `while (i < n_tokens + 1 && p != NULL)`. You can allocate for each token with `strdup`, e.g. `arr[i] = strdup (p);`. Now the contents of `arr[n]` will survive the return.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While I think you have probably got most of the issues sorted based on the comments, let's look at a way to address both the validation/return of `expressions` and a way to return the number of tokens to protect against an error in tokenization resulting in less than `n_tokens` being found.

As you have learned, when you declare `str2` local to `token_arr`, it has *automatic storage duration* and is only valid within the scope where it is declared. When `token_arr` returns, the memory holding `str2` is released for re-use and any attempt to reference that memory back in `main()` invokes *Undefined Behavior*.

What are your options? (1) use `strdup` to dynamically allocate storage for each token, copy the token to the new memory allocated, and then assign the starting address for the new block of memory containing the token to `arr[i]`, e.g.

```
        arr[i] = strdup (p);
```

or (2) do the same thing manually using `strlen, malloc & memcpy`, e.g.

```
        size_t len = strlen(p);
        arr[i] = malloc (len + 1);
        /* validate - here */
        memcpy (arr[i], p, len + 1);
```

Now each `arr[i]` points to a block of memory having *allocated storage duration* which remains valid until `free` is called on that block -- or the program ends.

**What If Less Than `n_tokens` Are Found?**

If less than `n_tokens` are found within `token_arr` and you attempt to use `n_tokens` through `expressions` back in `main()` you will likely invoke *Undefined Behavior* again. To ensure you only use the tokens found in `token_arr` and made available in `main()` by the assignment to `expression` -- *Pass A Pointer To* `n_tokens` as the second parameter and update it will the value of `i` before you `return arr;`, e.g.

```
char **token_arr (const char *str, int *n_tokens)
{
    char **arr = malloc(*n_tokens * sizeof *arr);
    ...
        i++;
    }
    *n_tokens = i;  /* assign i to make tokes assigned available */

    return arr;
}
```

Now `n_tokens` back in `main()` contains only the number of tokens actually found and allocated for and assigned to `arr[i]` in `token_arr`.

**Validate Every Allocation**

It is critical that you validate every call to `malloc, calloc, realloc, strdup` or any other function that allocates memory for you. Allocation can, and does, fail. When it does, it let's you know by returning `NULL` instead of a pointer containing the beginning address for the new block of memory. Check every allocation.

Putting it altogether, you could do something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char **token_arr (const char *str, int *n_tokens)
{
    char **arr = malloc(*n_tokens * sizeof *arr);
    char str2 [strlen(str) + 1];
    int i = 0;

    if (!arr) { /* validate every allocation */
        perror ("malloc-n_tokens");
        return NULL;
    }

    strcpy (str2, str);

    char *p = strtok (str2, " ");

    while (i < *n_tokens && p != NULL) {    /* check used pointers */
        arr[i] = strdup (p);
        if (!arr[i]) {  /* strdup allocates -> you must validate */
            perror ("strdup-arr[i]");
            if (i)          /* if tokens stored, break an return */
                break;
            else {          /* if no tokes stored, free pointers */
                free (arr);
                return NULL;
            }
        }
        p = strtok (NULL, " ");
        i++;
    }
    *n_tokens = i;  /* assign i to make tokes assigned available */

    return arr;
}

int main (void) {

    char *str1 = "( 8 + ( 41 - 12 ) )";
    int n_tokens = 9;
    char **expression = token_arr (str1, &n_tokens);

    if (expression) {       /* validate token_arr succeeded */
        for (int i = 0; i < n_tokens; i++) { /* n_tokens times */
            printf ("expression[%d] = %s\n", i, expression[i]);
            free (expression[i]);   /* free mem allocated by strdup */
        }
        free (expression);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

(**note:** likewise check the return of `token_arr` before making use of the return)

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/token_arr
expression[0] = (
expression[1] = 8
expression[2] = +
expression[3] = (
expression[4] = 41
expression[5] = -
expression[6] = 12
expression[7] = )
expression[8] = )
```

**Memory Use/Error Check**

In any code you write that dynamically allocates memory, you have 2 *responsibilities* regarding any block of memory allocated: (1) *always preserve a pointer to the starting address* for the block of memory so, (2) it can be *freed* when it is no longer needed.

It is imperative that you use a memory error checking program to insure you do not attempt to access memory or write beyond/outside the bounds of your allocated block, attempt to read or base a conditional jump on an uninitialized value, and finally, to confirm that you free all the memory you have allocated.

For Linux `valgrind` is the normal choice. There are similar memory checkers for every platform. They are all simple to use, just run your program through it.

```
$ valgrind ./bin/token_arr
==8420== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==8420== Copyright (C) 2002-2015, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==8420== Using Valgrind-3.12.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==8420== Command: ./bin/token_arr
==8420==
expression[0] = (
expression[1] = 8
expression[2] = +
expression[3] = (
expression[4] = 41
expression[5] = -
expression[6] = 12
expression[7] = )
expression[8] = )
==8420==
==8420== HEAP SUMMARY:
==8420==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==8420==   total heap usage: 10 allocs, 10 frees, 92 bytes allocated
==8420==
==8420== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==8420==
==8420== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==8420== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Always confirm that you have freed all memory you have allocated and that there are no memory errors.

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.